# Capacitor with a dielectric with only one plate / with one plate moving

Tags: energy, electrostatics, charge

I was wondering how a capacitor like the one in the picture below works. The length of the plates is *L* and their width is *b* (parallel to the z axis). The distance between the plates is *d*. The whole space between the plates is filled with a dielectric of relative permittivity *ε_r*. At the beginning the capacitor has charge Q. (picture a)

The lower plate is fixed to the ground but the upper one can be moved. Suppose it has moved a distance *x* along the x axis (picture b).

I was wondering what happens to the charge in this situation (assuming it is conserved). What are the charges *Q1*, *Q2*, *Q3*, *Q4*? What is the energy of this capacitor? I want to use the equation for the energy (derivating it with respect to *x*) to find the force stopping the movement of the upper plate (In my original problem, the capacitor is situated on a plane and the upper plate slides down due to the force of gravity).

The part with charge Q3 doesn't have any input, does it? Should I somehow include the part with charge *Q4*, even though there is only one plate there? I know there is a charge induced in the dielectric here and I can find it knowing *Q4* but I don't know how I should treat this part of the capacitor calculating the energy.

EDIT: We assume that *d* << *L* and *d* << *b*. Also: *x* >> *d* but *x* < *L* (in fact it will be *x* < *L*/2 in the original problem so that the upper plate won't rotate on that plane). For space outside the dielectric *ε_r* = 1.

[image]

Comment: I think you would need to know the dielectric permittivity of the material below Q3, or make some assumption about it

Comment: The only material there is the dielectric (light blue). The rest is free space.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this electrostatic problem exactly for an arbitrary plate distance $d$ and relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ would involve finding the electrostatic field in and around the capacitor with the moving plate which is rather difficult problem. Therefore I assume that the plate distance (and permittivity) are so small that the electric field is predominantly concentrated in the overlapping part $L-x$ of the capacitor.

Under this assumptions, the total initial charge $Q$ (which stays constant during the movement) is always located under the overlapping part of the upper plate because all the electric field is concentrated there. Thus the approximation $Q1=Q$ and $Q2=-Q$ holds for all $x$ until the upper plate is completely removed at $x=L$. This means that $Q4$ and $Q3$ are always zero.

Then the potential electrostatic energy of the capacitor is $$E=\frac{Q^2}{2 C}=\frac{Q^2 d}{2\epsilon_0\epsilon_r (L-x) b}$$ which results in a force  $$F=-\frac{dE}{dx}$$ you have to work against when moving the plate by increasing x. Obviously, for $x$ approaching L this not a good approximation anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct assumption. When $x=0$, the charge is uniformly distributed because of mutual repulsion, and is attracted to the opposite charge on the other side. I think the mutual repulsion may still dominate to some extent.

Comment: Also, typical relative permittivities are not so large, so the charge on the area that does not have a dielectric is not negligible. Although dielectric breakdown potentially is more likely over there

Comment: @Dr Xorile - You are at liberty to present an exact solution of the problem which also gives the charges $Q4$ and $Q3$. The one I gave is the only simple approximation to the solution in this case.

Comment: I forgot to add the assumptions for the measurements, edited the post.

Comment: @jcbula88 -Perfect! These are exactly the assumptions which make my solution in the above answer a very good approximation. They assure that the charge (and field) is concentrated in the overlap part of the capacitor.

Comment: @freecharly - Now I can see the protruding parts can't store energy because there can be no electric field there. But I'm still not sure about the assumption that the charge will always  stay on the (*L*-*x*) part (that *Q1* is always equal to *Q*). This was actually my first idea for this problem and I got the same equation as yours but I don't know if this is correct. Why exactly is that? Why won't some part of *Q* move to the *Q4* and *Q3* parts?

Comment: @freecharly - It seems the more I think about it the more problems I see. Where does the assumptions that there can be no field outside the *Q1* / *Q2* area come from?

Comment: @jcbula88 - There will, of course some charge also in the not overlapping parts. However, under the mentioned assumptions, these charges $Q3$ and $Q4$ are negligibly small as compared to the total charge $Q$. You can see this by assuming that the not overlapping capacitances $C4$ and $C3$ are small as compared to the overlapping capacitance (This also justifies the assumption of the parallel plate capacitor formula for the overlap.) Thus you have the total capacitance $C=C4+C_{overlap}+C3$ with the total charge $Q$ distributed proportional to the 3 capacitances. For $C4, C3≪C_{overlap}≈C$.

Comment: @jcbula88 - There are, of course, also some fields outside the overlap region. But the flux of these fields is much lower than the flux at the overlap. Therefore these fields can be neglected in the approximate solution of the problem.

Comment: @jcbula88 - This is actually also happening in a parallel plane capacitor where you neglect the fringing fields at the border so that you can use the parallel plate capacitance formula.

Comment: @freecharly - We don't have an assumption that *x* << *L* though. I don't see how the analogy to border effects would work here. *x* can be as big as *L*/2. Why would *Q4* and *Q3* be negligibly small compared to *Q1*?

Comment: @jcbula88 - You don't need the assumption $x<<L$. $Q4$ and $Q3$ are small compared to $Q1$ because the overlap capacitance is much larger than the (fringing) capacitances of the non-overlapping plate parts as long as L-x is not too small (therefore the original condition $x<L/2$).

Comment: @jcebula88 - Your condition $d<<L, b$ ensures that the fields are so strong in the overlap that the outer fields and thus their capacitances can be neglected, similar to the fringing fields in the plate capacitor. Otherwise you could not use the plate capacitor formula.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a simple 2D model, where there are some number of discrete charges distributed uniformly along each plate (=line). Then, to first approximation, each charge experiences a force from all the remaining charges (attractive for the opposite plates, and repulsive for the adjacent plates). These forces add together and cause the charge to move, constrained to the geometry of the plate. The force between the opposite plates is reduced by a factor of $\epsilon_r$ when there is a dielectric between them, or not reduced when there is no dielectric between them, or reduced by a proportion (see below).

A few model assumptions: $x=0.3$, $L=1$, $d=0.05$, $\epsilon_r=3$ and assume $n=30$ charges on the plate. Then, the charges remain broadly distributed on the plate:

[image: Charge distribution]

This is very unlike the fringe field of a parallel plate capacitor. In that situation, there is nowhere for the charge to go, and it goes broadly uniform because it is constrained to remain on the plates (if that constraint went away, the charges would disperse very rapidly, aka dielectric breakdown).

In this situation, you are giving the charges a conductor on which to move, and so, of course, they will happily. Yes, they are attracted to the charges on the opposite plate, but this is overwhelmed by the repulsion on the plate.

Here's what it looks like when $x=0$:

[image: Charge distribution when x=0]

Note that there is a little bit of bunching towards the ends. In this condition, the forces on the charges are balanced, except for the charges on the end, which are experiencing a force trying to get them to shoot sideways off the plate (and of course, there is an attractive force trying to get the charges to the opposite plate).

Even for $x=0.9$ this distributive force dominates:

[image: Charge distribution]

This is especially so, since the relative permittivity actually reduces the force experienced by the charges on either side of it. The qualitative behaviour does not change much with the other parameters.

A simple way to look at this is as a number of small capacitors in parallel (see the red lines in the diagram):

[image: Capacitor]

Each capacitor has a capacitance $\epsilon_r\frac{bdx}{4\pi\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}$ (you can see this methodology on page 159 of [this paper](http://file.scirp.org/pdf/JST20120300008_52414783.pdf)) (I'm assuming the dielectric extends, though this can be tweaked). Integrating this across the capacitor gives a capacitance of $C=\epsilon_r\frac{bL}{4\pi\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}=\epsilon_r\frac{A}{4\pi\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}$. This is a change in capacitance by a factor of $\frac{d}{\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}$.

Comment: So you are suggesting that the charge in each part of the plates is proportional to its area?

Comment: Exactly. Solving for the capacitance requires a solution of the laplace equation. Perhaps an approximation of the overlapping area can be used, but the charge will need to be reduced. I think the capacitance of the non-overlapping sections cannot be neglected, however.

Comment: Then what should I do with the non-overlapping parts if I want to calculate the total energy of this system?

Comment: I would expect that to first approximation, you could simply replace $d$ in the capacitance equation with $\sqrt{d^2+x^2}$, so your capacitance decreases by a factor of $d/\sqrt{d^2+x^2}$. This does not incorporate the area without a dielectric, but that should be simple to fix

Comment: This is not correct! When you have a capacitor with wire leads, you also have parallel capacitances due to the wires that are connected to the plates. But they are much smaller than the capacitance of the capacitor. Thus, in general,  you can neglect them.

Comment: @Dr Xorile - on what "intelligent guess" do you base your square root formulae?

Comment: My guess is based on the idea that you can view the system as an integral of smaller parallel plates at an angle. The distance between these plates is what I am considering.

Comment: I sense a certain level of aggression in your tone? Is everything okay?

Comment: In any event I wouldn't call my guess intelligent, necessarily. I saw a paper where a similar approach was used, but I'm not sure it would work here because it seems to neglect the importance of the overlap area. But I don't see how the charge can aggregate into one part of plate

Comment: @Dr Xorile - There is already too much discussion about this problem. There is no simple solution except for the parallel plate capacitance assumption for the overlap. The given conditions $d<<L,b$ and $x<L/2$ only confirm this view of the problem. You only need to make $d$ sufficiently small to ensure that any other parallel spurious capacitances  can be safely neglected. This should be obvious to anybody only marginally  familiar with electrostatics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48352/discussion-between-dr-xorile-and-freecharly).